What is the story behind the moving_ministry material icon? When do I use it, and what does it communicate to my users?
There is the moving_ministry material icon: moving_ministry

I considered using it to communicate "moving away/changing location" in context of a care-at-home mobile social services application.
Then I saw its name and started wondering. Are there situations where the occurrence of ministry buildings relocating is so prominent to warrant a specialized icon?
When I use it to mean any other kind of real estate movement, am I in violation of a material design guideline?


Are there situations where the occurrence of ministry buildings relocating is so prominent to warrant a specialized icon?

Probably not. The icon set also contains other extremely niche and probably unnecessary icons, such as "Nest Thermostat Zirconium Eu", "Hangout Video Off", "Sword Rose" or "Unknown 5". It is likely that a designer at Google needed that icon for some one-off purpose, but because they already had made it, it got added to the database. The person naming it and the person making the icon may not be the same and may never have talked to each other.

When I use it to mean any other kind of real estate movement, am I in violation of a material design guideline?

You cannot violate a design guideline - they're guidelines, not laws. The point is to communicate something to a person, and the guidelines contain best practices which are typically useful to follow - unless you have a concrete reason not to. And you do have a reason - it's an icon that describes what you want to do somewhat well. move_location, move may or may not be an acceptable alternative, as may doctoring an arrow onto the home or house icon yourself (similar to the exisiting wifi_home icon).
The ultimate question would be if the icon itself communicates its purpose well enough - or whether it needs to be accompanied by, or perhaps entirely replaced by a text button instead. That would be up to your users to tell you though.
